# stupid `NetTrain[]` question

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Consider this sequence:

```
net = NetInitialize[
  NetChain[{LinearLayer[100], LogisticSigmoid, LinearLayer[100], 
    LogisticSigmoid, LinearLayer[100], LogisticSigmoid, 
    LinearLayer[100], LogisticSigmoid, LinearLayer[1] }, 
   "Input" -> {2, 11}]]

net = NetTrain[net, foo]
```

Tells me that the first element to `NetTrain[]` should be a fully specified net. But what is it about the net that is underspecified?

Comment: Probably fails for some other reason (wrong data input format for `foo`?). Don't assign the output of `NetTrain` to `net` again, if it fails it would reassign it to something like `$Failed` and wouldn't work anymore.

Comment: Post foo please

Comment: @M.R. sure thing: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o88f3zpph5k4tze/foo?dl=0

Comment: @swish Actually, assigning the output to `newnet` does not give the error any more, and trains fine! Weird.

Comment: That call to netinitialize is redundant

Comment: As @swish suggests, this problem is due to something like `NetTrain[$Failed,foo]`. For example, run this `net = NetTrain[net, {RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 11}] -> 1}]` and then `net = NetTrain[net, {RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 11}] -> {1}}]` you will get the exact same error message, although the second expression is correct.

Answer (score 2):

As swish hinted, the problem may due to an incorrect previous return. For example:

```
net = NetInitialize[
  NetChain[{LinearLayer[100], LogisticSigmoid, LinearLayer[100], 
    LogisticSigmoid, LinearLayer[100], LogisticSigmoid, 
    LinearLayer[100], LogisticSigmoid, LinearLayer[1]}, 
   "Input" -> {2, 11}]]
```

If we provide the incorrect training data, NetTrain fails with an error message

```
net = NetTrain[net, {RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 11}] -> 1}]
(* $Failed *)
```

> NetTrain::invindim: Data provided to port "Output" should be a list of
>   length-1 vectors.

Now if you run the training again with the correct data, you get the same error message in your question

```
net = NetTrain[net, {RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 11}] -> {1}}]
(* $Failed *)
```

> NetTrain::invnet: First argument to NetTrain should be a fully
>   specified net.

This is because, in the second run, the net has a value of `$Failed`, which is not a neural network.